# Using Underscore's _.throttle in a function declaration

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm curious as to why wrapping a function with _.throttle does not work in a function declaration. This function expression behaves as expected:

```
var myFunc = _.throttle(function(){
   console.log("I'm throttling");
}, 1000);
```

Though this does not:

```
function myFunc(){
    return _.throttle(function(){console.log("I'm throttling");}, 1000);
}
```

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`_.throttle`](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) will return a throttled version of the current function. In the first case, you are invoking `_.throttle`, and you are getting the throttled function object. So, when you simply do

```
myFunc();
```

it invokes your actual function. But in the second case, you are returning the throttled function from the `myFunc` function. So, until you invoke `myFunc`, the `_.throttle` will not be invoked at all. You have to call the outer function to get the throttled version and then invoke that function to get the result, you expect.

```
myFunc()();
```

As pointed out by idbehold in the comments, you should store the result of `myFunc()` in a variable and then use it subsequent calls, like this

```
var throttledVersion = myFunc();
throttledVersion();
throttledVersion();
...
```

But prefer the first version.